# Adding 0 (Zero) as Key in array doesn't work but when i change it to 1 it works

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm still confused why when i use 0 as key in array it does not work but when i changed it to 1 it works normally. Can someone explain me why this is happening.
Thanks in advance.

## $myArray = {1,2,3,4}

## Using foreach loop to get the data and to add to my new array

```
 $o = array();
 foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
     //using to $key to set the key for item in my array 
     $o[$key] = $value;
  }
```

## Output should be like this

## $o={0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4}

But when the key start with 0 it returns like this

## $o={1,2,3,4}

When i change it to

```
$o = array();
 foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
     //using to $key to set the key for item in my array 
     $o[$key+1] = $value;
  }
```

## the ouput

## $o={1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4}

## my main goal ouput

## $o={0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4}

Comment: could you please provide a var_dump of your $key? also - please provide your code as actual code, not as screenshot.

Comment: @Paul is it a associative array or numeric array

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i updated my question

Comment: if this is a `var_dump($key)`, then there is really a lot wrong. plus: please don't post screenshots, post text...

Comment: @user3099298 Associative

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I can't post the actual output because JS is doing the process so i prefer screenshots

Comment: @Paul i have soooo many question marks right now. please post all of the relevant code from your editor, which you *can* copy&paste, as well as expected output (which you *can* copy&paste, as i can see by your first screenshot where you marked it, just hit ctrl+c) and your actual output. and a `var_dump($key)` of your offending key. (as text. not screenshot)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann lemme edit my question first

Comment: @FranzGleichmann check my question

Comment: @Paul your question did not improve in quality. please - complete code. where does $optiondata come from? what is the content of the offending $key? how do you output your data? also, in your first code sample, the foreach-loop is complete and utter waste of processing power - it just creates an exact duplicate of $optiondata, which can be achieved by `$o=$optiondata;`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann oops my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this,

```
<?php

$o = array(1,2,3,4);

$bind = array();
foreach($o as $key=>$value){
    $bind[] = $key.":".$value;
}

echo implode( ',', $bind );

?>


Output: 0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4
```